# minimize pseudo norm over an affine subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-programming

Suppose $A$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix, and K is a subspace. Let $y$ be any minimizer of $x^TAx$, where $\ x\in x_0 + K$.

Then $Ay\perp K$.

It is clear true when $A$ is identity, but I have no idea how to prove the general case. I was also wondering if the positive definite and symmetric conditions of $A$ are both necessary.

Thanks.

PS: The question can be also stated as 
$$ \text{min}\ y^TAy$$
$$ \text{subject to}\ By = c$$
where $K = \text{ker}\ B$ and $Bx_0 = c$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the KKT conditions is
$$2 A y + B^\top \lambda = 0$$
for some vector $\lambda$. Rearranging shows that $Ay$ is in the column space of $B^\top$, which is the same as the row space of $B$, which is orthogonal to $\ker B = K$.